# genealogytree Right to Left

Tags: right-to-left, genealogytree

is there any work available for right to left typesetting which is enabling the **genealogytree**? Greetings

*I already searched and didn't find any reliable resource.*

Comment: Have you seen this guide first of all? http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/genealogytree/genealogytree.pdf.

Comment: Yes, I have seen it, but I don't know how to change the typesetting for left-to-right to right-to-left.

Comment: the solution is to add: halign=flush right